# Bulk upload of pictures to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am trying to help a friend set up the Facebook Page for my class reunion. Is there a way to allow Fans of a Page to bulk upload pics to the Photo app? I have never set up a Page, so I am going at this blind. Currently, the only way to upload a photo is to upload it to the Wall, which doesn't seem practical for bulk uploads.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way for a fan to bulk upload to Facebook Pages.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's a security feature to prevent [spamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_%28electronic%29) and [flooding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_flood).

Answer (score 1):

Set up a group instead to enable bulk uploads